# TFS17 on prem and fortify builds

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, fortify

I need to incorporate a task in my build to perform a Fortify Scan.  My issue is I have one agent and scans take 1 to 2 hours, which ties up the one agent.  I then tried to create a build that would start a scan of are TFS/SCM only to kill it after it ran for over 8 hours.  Is there a way to create a task that only runs the changes for that day?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Team Foundation Server 2017. As part of your build and release process you could execute **Micro Focus Fortify security** scans and upload the results to the Fortify SSC server.

It's also able to make the build/release fail whenever the scanner detects new critical or high findings in the code. We could use the Micro Focus Fortify plugin for TFS to configure the scan step and upload to SSC: ([Fortify TFS plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fortifyvsts.hpe-security-fortify-vsts#overview)). Just add  a PowerShell task afterward to attempt to query for findings and fail the build if needed.

Is there a way to create a task that only runs the changes for that day? There is also a concept called  **Scheduled Trigger** which select the days and times when you want to run the build. Just make sure to check "Only schedule builds if the source and pipeline has changed"  All support triggers are list here --[Build pipeline triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic), please kindly take  a look at it.

Comment: Is there a way to create a task that only runs the changes for that day? if someone checks in there code, it there a way to only scan that code.  Example (TFSProject/ProgramA and TFSProject/ProgramB.  If someone makes a changes to ProgramB and checks it in, it gets built.  I would also like to scan ProgramB after hours say 1:00 AM.)  We are using the TFS Plugin, but it seems to only run in line of the build and not something that can be saved for later in the day.

Comment: Hi @StephanM Sorry for the later reply. "I would also like to scan Program B after hours say 1:00 AM." There is also a concept called  **Scheduled Trigger** which select the days and times when you want to run the build. Just make sure to check "Only schedule builds if the source and pipeline has changed"  All support triggers are list here --[Build pipeline triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic), please kindly take  a look at it.

Comment: Hi StephanM, any update on this ticket? Did you get a chance to implement the solution that I suggested? Were you able to resolve?

Comment: No Update, I am still working my way through trying to get a clean Fortify run.  It seems to hang up when running the task from with in TFS using the fortify Template or the CMD Line Template.  If I log on to the server it works.